# Mysql Date Encryption

Tags: mysql, date, encryption

I am using AES_ENCRYPT method to encrypt the Mysql data's but when i tried it for Mysql Date type field which is not working. How to encrypt Mysql Date field using the AES_ENCRYPT? I have tried it by googleing it but no luck so far.

Comment: You need to pass a String to AES_ENCRYPT. Convert the date to a string and you should have your answer.

Comment: Do you mean that the Date field should be created as String field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the mysql manual:

```
AES_ENCRYPT() encrypts a string and returns a binary string. 
AES_DECRYPT() decrypts the encrypted string and returns the original string. 
The input arguments may be any length. 
If either argument is NULL, the result of this function is also NULL.
```

This means you need to store encrypted data in a column of varchar or text type.

Comment: Hmmmm then mysql encryption functions will not help to encrypt the Date field like DOB? or is there any customized way for this?

Comment: For each date column "mydate" of type date you would create a column "mydate_enc" of string type instead. This would of course mess up date mappings if you are using an object-relational-mapper.